# how to get all sub admin area's / districts for a country

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

We are developing an android application and we are able to find out the users location using the `Geocoder` class.

Now after getting the location of the user we want to display some content which is specific to that area / locality. Our contents are grouped based upon the sub admin area, which we are getting using `getSubAdminArea()` of the `Address` class.

Now we are able to know the sub admin area, name of the user. But we are concerned that the sub admin area name entries which we will have in our table, may not match to that returned by google. In this case we won't be able to achieve our functionality.

So my question is, "is there any way by which we can get all the sub admin area's for a country using google map. So that we can populate those and there will be no chances of any mismatch. Basically we are trying to get all sub admin area / districts present in India.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a data-set of all the sub admin areas for India (or any country for that matter) used within Google maps are not available publicly. However, there's a way you can get those for specific addresses that you would want to use.

This is a rather lengthy process so its totally your choice if you want to go through with it.

1) Make an individual Geocoding request for all the addresses. For example: *https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TajMahal+Agra*
2) You will get all the admin area levels and sub localities that Google maps has for each location.
3) Check with your database and you should be good to go.

Useful links:
[These](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) are address types and components within gmaps.
This the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_exists) for `geocoder`.
[Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for geocoding API just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I have extracted all of them, using reverse geocoding. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Glad I could help!